# Xcode 8.3 settings

Tags: ios, xcode

I am new to Xcode and have two questions.

1. Main.storyboard: I want to see the whole iPhone, but now 2/3 of the screen is a white background. How to fit it to show only the whole device ?   [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLt6e.png)
2. I noticed that when I get an exception, there are some new windows opened in Xcode and I just can't get back to my previously opened stuff without manually closing these new windows and starting again which is pretty frustrating; how can I prevent it ?

   Additional explanation: first problem
   a) I set zoom and resize the window (upper image)
   b) I click button in upper right corner (middle image)
   c) Now I click this button once again to go back - but everything gets messed up and I need to manually resize it again  [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLt6e.png)

I just want my device to be fixed as it is in AndroidStudio for example.

Comment: provide some screen shot for the second problem

Answer (score 0):

The solution for your first problem is like right click on the main.storyboard then you will see a menu of options where you can set the appropriate zoom level

Please provide some screenshots for the second problem.